# How to rewrite URL in NGINX with location parameter?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, openproject

i have a Application (Openproject) on a Webserver.
this is Reachable under http://10.0.0.1:8000/

Behind my users and the Webserver is a NGinx on which i need to publish under a specific URL: https://ngrp.com/openproject

so i made the following changes in my Nginx Configuaion (in this NGINX instance multiple Websites are published with the "location" settings):

```
  location /openproject/ {
   proxy_pass             http://10.0.0.1:8000/;
   include                /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
 }
```

But when i open the page through the Reverseproxy, the Webbrowser displays only a White Page.

---

In the Webbrowser Debugger i see, that some paths are wrong, so the browser couldn´t load it. Example:

https://ngrp.com/assets/frontend/styles.c3a5e7705d6c5db9cfc1.css
(/openproject/ is missing in the URL)

Correct would be:

https://ngrp.com/openproject/assets/frontend/styles.c3a5e7705d6c5db9cfc1.css

So can somebody please tell me, which configuration is needed, so i can Openproject under the URL https://ngrp.com/openproject/ successfully?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When you `proxy_pass` you proxy the entire HTTP request meaning that you are actually requesting `GET /openproject` on http://10.0.0.1:8000/ rather than just `GET /`

You can add this line before the proxy_pass to fix this and remove the `/openproject` prefix :

`rewrite /openproject/(.*) /$1  break;`

This changes the requested URL from `/openproject/...` to `/...`

Comment: Hi Misfits09,

first Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunatelly it didn´t work:

i placed the following Configpart in the NGINX:

  location /openproject/ {
    rewrite /openproject/(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass             http://10.0.0.1:8000/;
    include                /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;

But the same Problem exists. 
https://ngrp.com/assets/frontend/styles.c3a5e7705d6c5db9cfc1.css (/openproject/ is missing in the URL)

have you another idea?